# When closing and opening vscode, all extensions need to be downloaded again (after mac migration)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I migrated my Mac to another Mac and after doing so I changed the user directory name. This has already caused many issues in other applications but I haven't been able to solve the code issue.

The problem:
Every time I open a new instance of vscode it opens with no installed extensions at all despite having installed many.

I am not very familiar with Mac yet and I have tried removing the App and redownloading as well as deleting some files from the ~/Library folder (cookies, preferences).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue on Github with a workaround at the bottom of the issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168579

Basically, every new extension installed correctly but in the extensions.json file the path was wrong. It was looking for the extension in the wrong user directory (the old one before migrating).